# Getting incorrect outputs, not sure why. Is there a problem with the way I fill/print my arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This program creates a multiplication table of an input width and height, and then prints the values. It works fine for squares. It works when width < height, but still prints the error message `Index n out of bounds for length n`. It does not work when width > height (prints some values, but then stops and doesn't display an error). It does not work for a 1*n or n*1 table.

I have tried changing < to <=, but I can't really see what's wrong in the code.

```
class Main {
  public static int[][] createMultiplicationArray(int width, int height){
    int[][] multiGrid = new int[width][height]; //Creating grid
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i ++){
      for(int j = 0; j < height; j ++){
        multiGrid[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1); //Filling grid
      }
    }
    return multiGrid;
  }
  public static void printGrid(int[][] multiGrid){
  for(int i = 0; i < multiGrid[0].length; i ++){ //Repeating for width
    for(int j = 0; j < multiGrid[1].length; j ++){ //Repeating for height
      System.out.println(multiGrid[i][j]);
    }
  }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Multiplication Grid");
    System.out.print("Enter a number for width: ");
    int width = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Thanks you! Now, enter a number for height: ");
    int height = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[][] multiGrid = createMultiplicationArray(width, height);
    printGrid(multiGrid);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of multiGrid[0].length, just use multiGrid.length

Comment: @Tarun This fixed the width > height problem, so thanks. However, a 1 wide or high table is still not possible.

Comment: When it throws that IndexOutOfBoundsException, the stacktrace should tell you exactly which one of your lines has triggered it. So, which statement is it?

Comment: It is because when you initialize it using 1, the max length is 1. And in the inner loop, you are trying to access multiGrid[1] and this will throw an exception. To avoid all this just use enhanced forloop. If you don't want to use enhanced for loop you will have to add checks for negative cases.

Comment: @ Tarun I have now fixed it so it works for all widths and heights by changing some details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through your 2D array, don't use `multiGrid[0].length` (for `i` loop) or `multiGrid[1].length` (for `j` loop). Instead use these respectively: `multiGrid.length` and `multiGrid[i].length`. After all, a Two Dimensional Array in Java is an Array of Arrays. There is no law that states that the inner Arrays all need to have the same length.

To display something that might resemble a multiplication table you can use the `System.out.printf()` method, for example:

```
public static void printGrid(int[][] multiGrid) {
    // Rows...  
    for (int i = 0; i < multiGrid.length; i++) { 
        // Columns...
        for (int j = 0; j < multiGrid[i].length; j++) { 
            System.out.printf("%-5s", multiGrid[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If a height of `10` (rows) is supplied and a width of `12` (columns) is supplied then the Console will display:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   
2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24   
3    6    9    12   15   18   21   24   27   30   33   36   
4    8    12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48   
5    10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50   55   60   
6    12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60   66   72   
7    14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70   77   84   
8    16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96   
9    18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90   99   108  
10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100  110  120
```